# Onclick function triggered by pressing specific key on keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

Is it possible to trigger click event which is attached on button with specific keyCode in React? For now my calculator works by clicking the buttons. But my goal is to make it work both - clicking or typing numbers on NUM pad.

All buttons have on click event which triggers function depending on its name. Buttons with Numbers trigger `getNumber()` function which takes buttons name and store it in state. Then state is sent as a prop to display component and displayed . Operator buttons trigger `operator()` function which takes operator from buttons name and its used in calculations.

I've tried to Google it but all I could find was just firing click event on 'send' button while typing in `<input>`element, and  I think that's whole different thing.

Then I've decided to try it like this

```
    document.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
      if(e.which == 97){
        document.getElementsByName('1')[0].click();     
      }
    });
```

My idea was to add condition with specific keyCode for every keyboard button I would use (0-9 and +-*/. and enter for result).
I didn't think that's right solution for it, but i gave that a shot and it doesn't work well.

When I press NUM1 for the first time everything's good, '1' appears in calculator display, but when I press it again, result is not '11' as expected but '111'. After another hit result is not '111' but '1111111' and so on. There is some strange multiplication going on.

Funny thing happened when I put it in codesandbox, so I can share it with you  here. After press NUM1 just one time 9 ones pop up in display. I don't get that.

**Link**

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-platform-n6lvs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 issues. The first is something that pretty much always eventually gets React developers at some point.
When in development mode and using `React.Strict`, your `App` function is called twice. This is normal behavior. This is why you are getting `11` on the first press, you bound the `keydown` event twice.

React also refreshes the app after each paint. So every time that you did an effect, `keydown` was bound more times. Hence the additional `1`s each press. The solution to both of these is to call your event binding in a hook. Normally, if you were using classes, you'd use the `Mount` hooks. Since you're doing a function, you can do a workaround by replaceing this:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
  if(e.which == 97){
    document.getElementsByName('1')[0].click();     
  }
});
```

With

```
useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      if (e.which === 97) {
        document.getElementsByName("1")[0].click();
      }
    });
  }, []); //this array should be empty
```

This basically is telling the app to run this one time when it first paints and then again each time a component in the array is updated. Since the array is empty, this function is never called again (which is what you want).

There are definitely better ways to do this kind of functionality, but this will probably be the cleanest to implement without refactoring the rest of your project.

P.S. Don't forget that many keyboards have 2 keys for each number/symbol and that these keys have different keycodes :)

P.P.S You may want to look into `e.repeat` eventually. That will probably be useful for this project.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation and answer ! I’m pretty much new to React ,so I’m not very familiar with all options and functions which React offers. I was wondering why everytime when I console logged something ,it was Logged twice :D . Now I understand . So my idea of solution wasn’t bad ,i just have to use it with useEffect. I’ll try it tomorrow :)